# Question about meaning of the line from Modern Family (season 2 episode 5)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

In the TV show Modern Family (season 2 episode 5), Mitchell called Claire for some advice about preschools he's picking for his daughter, he said:

> "Hey, it's me. **What's a good preschool**?"

I am confused about the meaning of the bold part, does it mean that "do you know any good preschool"?

Answer (score 2):

What's a good [thing]? - give me an example of a good [thing].

What's a good car for a new driver? What's a good Indian restaurant in our town?